# Revert Git rebase that is pushed to origin

Tags: git, version-control, rebase, git-revert

I did some changes in my feature branch. Before pushing, I rebased it to master branch
ON BRANCH Feature(featureBranch) ->
`git rebase master`

then i pushed it

`git push origin featureBranch`

Then I realised I should not have rebased master but dev.
I did `git reflog`, found out head (headId) when rebase started.

```
git reset (headId)
git reset --heard (headId)
```

Now i have some untracked files and origin feature branch is still not updated.
How do I revert rebase to origin feature branch?

Comment: Why have you copied your own explanation...

Comment: Also formatting please. People really don't want to help you if you don't even bother to explain your problem clearly in an easy to process way.

Comment: @Kim As a new user, OP is likely using the new question assistant, which in separate input fields asks you to describe different parts of the question (setup, what you tried, what you want, etc.) Then it merges them into the post. I suspect that is what happened here.